# QGIS project wise grant to Users created in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have created multiple projects IN QGIS  and saved them in PostgreSQL. It has created a table in Public schema as 'QGIS_Projects' and creates rows to save different projects from QGIS . I have given 'Select' grant to users for this project table. I am now unable to give grants to users based on the different QGIS projects :
Example: QGIS _PROJECT 1 -- Select grant only to user A
Example: QGIS _PROJECT 2 -- Select grant only to user B

How can I do this?

Comment: It's far from certain that row-level security would work this way, but you should certainly research it and try.

Comment: How to I restrict a user based on QGIS project then ?

Comment: There are several large questions lurking just below the surface here. Given that there's one `public` table, it doesn't seem that this kind of security model was envisioned (since it's open source, you can research this, too). But first you need to research the basic security model of PostgreSQL, then the row-level security extension. Once you understand how it *could* work, then you need to research how it *does* work. At that point you'll be able to ask a more focused question.